# Using twitch API to retrieve whole gaming section channels

Tags: php, api, channel, twitch

Well, I figured out the api for single channel, but can't figure how to retrieve whole gaming section.
I am failing to utilize api, I keep getting Notice:

> Undefined index: id in F:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php on line 13

```
$totalstreamers = $json_array['_total'];
echo $totalstreamers;

$id = $json_array['streams']['id'];
```

It is showing total streamers but I cannot figure the id part.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way I did was to search streams of a certain game which could look like:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=Minecraft
```

A list of streams will be returned descending on viewer count

you will get 25 as default in this array, use offset to skip through all pages.